# VMWare ESXi 5.0 Connection reset by peer

Tags: connection, vmware, esxi

I have an ESXi box setup in a remote location. Trying to connect to it today with vSphere results with this error:

"The client could not send a complete request to the server. (The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.))"

[image: screenshot of error message]

- I have tried multiple versions of Windows.
- The IP is pingable.
- Chrome    returns "Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" when I try to
  navigate to    port 80.
- Nmap returns that ports are open.
- I have tried multiple    machines.
- The VM's are active and working fine.

When I get over the datacenter I will attempt to reboot the box unless anyone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to post the answer. But for anyone who encounters this in the future:

I had to physically restart the management network on the box itself and I could access the vCenter again.